# BeanPostProcessor relying on other bean instance (causing Bean (...) is not eligible...)

Tags: java, spring

I am facing the *Bean (...) is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors*. I've narrowed down the issue to a @Bean method in @Configuration class, which I believe is the culprit:

Config class

```
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Config {

    private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor classABeanPostProcessor() {
        return new BeanPostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean instanceof ClassA) {
                    SomeOtherStaticClasss.doSomething(meterRegistry);
                }

                return bean;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From what I understand, the BeanPostProcessor bean is created fairly quickly, requiring the MeterRegistry bean to be instantiated prematurely, which makes it *not eligible* (as BeanPostProcessors are operating on yet not injected beans).

I've came up across this blog post which described a very similar issue: https://blog.monosoul.dev/2021/04/02/who-stole-my-spring-boot-system-metrics/
Thing is, I don't quite understand how the @Bean method producing "badRestTemplateReplacement" works, as the MetricsRestTemplateCustomizer (which relys on the MeterRegistry bean instance) needs to be injected as well?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand why it's ok in the example from the blog post - this is simply bean definition at the time being and nothing forces it to instantiate prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found a solution by simply using @Lazy (I also extracted the classABeanPostProcessor definition as @Component):

```
    @Component
    public static class ClassABeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

        private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

        @Lazy
        public ClassABeanPostProcessor(final MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
            this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
        }

        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof ClassA) {
                SomeOtherStaticClasss.doSomething(meterRegistry);
            }
            return bean;
        }
    }
```